# Any innovations in mathematical processes behind option pricing models?

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes

I am working on my thesis about option pricing models beyond classical Black-Scholes Model by looking for some recent **innovations on **mathematical processes behind the pricing structures****. By that I mean doing some essential modification on traditional GBM framework or even replaced it with other mathematical processes, such as Levy's process (or some novel stuff). So far, I have found Neural SDEs to be a good starting point to this topic, since it replaces the fixed parameters in models like BSM and Heston's volatility model by neural networks. But I wonder if there are other scholar work introducing new mathematical frameworks of pricing model?

Any help is appreciated. Hopefully I could get some advice from researchers or pricing engineers as an undergraduate...

Comment: Take a look at https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/25459/dave-harris. He has some working papers on SSRN that you may find intriguing.